# Convert dictionary from wide to long form using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a list of dictionaries in Python with different keys (Response Key is present in all ) and I want to convert it into a Panda Dataframe such that all key-values are shown as rows with **Response** Key value repeating as a Column. For instance, following list

**[** {'**Response**': 1, 'work life': 5, 'life family': 2, 'family balance': 10}, 
{'**Response**': 2, 'encouragement management': 11, 'management career': 1, 'career aspirations': 4, 'aspirations develop': 8},{'**Response**': 3, 'encourage people': 15, 'people managers': 9, 'managers ask': 5, 'ask employees': 9} **]**

should become 3-column dataframe as

```
Response | Attribute | Value
1, work life, 5
1, life family, 2
1, family balance, 10
2, encouragement management, 11
2, management career, 1
2, career aspirations, 4
2, aspirations develop, 8
3, encourage people, 15
3, people managers, 9
3, managers ask, 5
3, ask employees, 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for. Use `stack` and then reset the index and column names.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('Response').stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Response', 'Attribute', 'Value']

df

    Response                 Attribute  Value
0          1            family balance   10.0
1          1               life family    2.0
2          1                 work life    5.0
3          2       aspirations develop    8.0
4          2        career aspirations    4.0
5          2  encouragement management   11.0
6          2         management career    1.0
7          3             ask employees    9.0
8          3          encourage people   15.0
9          3              managers ask    5.0
10         3           people managers    9.0
```

`d` is your dictionary data. Keep in mind that dictionaries are *not ordered*, so it is unreasonable to always expect the same order as in your question.

Comment: You're awesome...Thanks!!